# How to prevent propagation of events from a specific component in Angular?

Tags: angular

**TLDR:**

Is there a way to ensure events fired by a specific component are not propagated to outside that component?

Alternatively, slightly less preferable: Is there a way to make the `@HostListener` defined in a given `Directive` injected in a component, to ignore events fired by another specific sibling component?

**Context for Clarification**:

Suppose I have a page that looks like this:

[image: page layout]

The parent component (1) includes a list of rows (child component (3)) and a form on top (another child component (2)). The form includes an input field.

I intend to allow users to navigate the list by keyboard on pressdown of `j` and `k` which slightly changes background color of one of the rows. I have implemented that by introducing a `Directive` in component (3) that uses `HostListener` to listen to pressdown events of `j` and `k`.

```
  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    // pressing keys 'i' and 'j' should navigate through list of suites
    if (['j', 'k'].includes(event.key)) {
      this.navigate(event.key);
    }
  }
```

The issue with this approach is that this directive, even when injected in component 3, appears to capture **any** pressdown event of `j` and `k` in the entire page including when user is typing a text in the input field of form in component 2 which happens to have characters `j` and `k`.

To avoid that, I want, either to make the Directive smart enough to ignore events fired by component 2, or to make sure events of Component 2 are never propagated outside.

Answer (score 0):

After learning more about DOM event propagation, I may have found a solution to my problem by registering a separate `HostListener` for component 2 (the form) that captures particular `pressdown` events and stops them from propagation to parent or other components in the document, using [Event.stopImmediatePropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation):

```
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (['j', 'k'].includes(event.key)) {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
  }
```

This may be generic enough to wrap into a separate Directive to use on various elements that may trigger unwanted events. Not sure if it is a good practice though.